# ASUS GPU R9 290 Direct CU II Turns off under load (without fans)

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-failure

**tldr**: I broke my 2 fans on GPU by cleaning them and ordered new ones (which will arive only in 2 weeks). First fan doesn't spin at all and second wiggles, but won't start spinning. I also noticed some strange behaviour of my GPU:

1. If I disconnect the the fans (what is left of them) from GPU and
   try to turn on the computer - screen stays black. I guess this is
   some kind of hardware protection from running it without fans -
   which is okay I guess.
2. If I connect the fans to GPU and boot into OS (doesn't matter
   which one - Linux, Windows or mac OS). GPU works fine until the
   temperature hits 70˚per Celsius (158 Fahrenheit) after that
   screen turns off and I am able to turn the PC off only by holding
   the power button. After that, it boots normally and everything
   repeats after heating up GPU to 70. Is it also some kind of
   protection or I damaged the GPU? This GPU could have handled up to
   90 degrees per Celsius before all of this happened. Also this is
   definitely not the PSU issue - this is out of the question.

**Update**: I noticed that it could go higher than 70˚ if I heat it up slowly - watching a video for example, but it also turns off later. It seems like it can't handle quick increase in core and memory clocks - screen goes black immediately.

**Question**: So the question is will my GPU work normally when I replace the fans with new ones (they are identical) or there is something wrong with the GPU?

Is there also some kind of protection because fans are not spinning and PWM doesn't send any data to GPU?

I thought that GPU should heat up to max operating temperatures regardless fan conditions (94˚), but it seems that it is not the case...

Comment: Your GPU is a obviously overheating.  I see no reason to believe working fans will present a problem.  Once the GPU doesn’t overheat it should work provided, overheating, hasn’t caused a problem.  So stop using it.

Comment: this card should handle ~90˚ per Celsius just fine - it is designed to work at this temperature. But what I see - black screen after 70, which I consider strange.

Comment: What's your question, actually? You know that you have no working fans while there should be two, you know that the GPU is overheating. It's not working properly, which is to be expected.

Comment: Questing is: Why it turns off after 70, not 95?

Comment: @AlexanderNovikov So the card isn’t damaged.

Comment: Careful: Some cards need the fan airflow to cool the VRM. And a damaged overheated VRM can send 12V to the chip, grilling it instantly. Consider macgyvering a spare CPU or case fan onto the card.